# How to use mirrorOf in Maven

Tags: maven, nexus

What is the difference between using

```
<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
```

and

```
   <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

We have a Nexus server running proxied to the Maven public repository and using "*" instead of "central" downloads some artifiacts but not all.

Reading http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html does not suggest what could cause this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
```

says if request comes to lookup for central maven repository look in its mirror instead

where

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

says for any request to download from any repository look in this mirrored repository

if you have second and if it is failing to download some artifacts it could be because you are not proxying certain repository in your own nexus repository

Comment: I'm not following how a request comes in that is "directed" to central.  When a maven dependency is declared, it doesn't specify a repo, so how is it mapped to "central"?

Comment: @PatS in the plain setup (without any customization) Maven gets to know about "central" from its default `settings.xml` file. https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.  I, incorrectly, thought there was a list somewhere that I wasn't aware of.  If I'm understanding this correctly, each `<mirror>` element specifies an `id`, and the `<mirrorOf>` simply uses the ID that was also defined in the `settings.xml` file.  And `central` is the name of the default repo.  Is this the correct understanding?